# SQL Server Copy records from one column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to pass data from one column to another column in the same table?i.e:

```
create table tb_usuarios_voar
(
    int_id_usu int identity(1,1),
    int_re_usu int not null,
    txt_colaborador varchar(200) null,
    txt_cargo varchar(200) null,
    txt_chefearea_usu varchar(150) null,
    txt_estrutura varchar(200) null,
    txt_marca varchar(200) null,
    txt_unidade varchar(150) null
)
```

That is the original table.Then ive added a new column:

```
alter table tb_usuarios_voar add txt_password varchar(140) null
```

What i want is to copy all records from int_re_usu column to the new column txt_password.

Any ideias?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
update tb_usuarios_voar set txt_password = convert(varchar, int_re_usu)
```